# way to store and use users input

Tags: c#

I need to work with the input given by the user,how can i get the integer and char input from user and how to store it and how to use it for manipulation in c#

Comment: The question is extremely general. Provide more details. What type of application you are developing ? (GUI, CUI, WEB ....) where you need it yo store ? (File, DB....). More details .....

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple console program that asks a user for his or her name, stores the input in a string variable, and then asks a question where the only valid response is an integer, and continues to prompt the user if an invalid input is provided. It then redisplays the user's answers on the screen.

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("What is your name?  ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            bool validInput = false;
            int inputDays = 0;
            int actualDays = 7;

            while (!validInput)
            {
                Console.Write("How many days are in a week?  ");
                string response = Console.ReadLine();
                validInput = int.TryParse(response, out inputDays);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0}, you said there are {1} days in a week. This is {2}.", name, inputDays, inputDays == actualDays);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```